# Inserting Master database data into my database table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I put a trigger on one table on update, and I want to insert the last 15 executed queries into a table. Last executed queries are in the MASTER database as

```
SELECT top(15) dest.text AS [Query]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs

   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
      --inner join  sys.sysprocesses
     -- on sys.sysprocesses.sql_handle=deqs.sql_handle

      ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

How can I insert these 15 queries into my database table as string? The trigger I am using is like this.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[uom_cu]
ON  [dbo].[saleExpStockID] after update

AS 

INSERT INTO zzuomupdate(date_cu, Query_r) 
VALUES(getdate(), (SELECT top(15) dest.text AS [Query]
    FROM master.sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs

   CROSS APPLY master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest

      ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC))
```

Answer (score 1):

I very seriously question the use of a trigger here.  Your trigger is going to dramatically slow down the updates of your table.  That being said your query should look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO zzuomupdate(date_cu, Query_r) 
SELECT top(15) getdate(), dest.text AS [Query]
FROM master.sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

The way you had it you were trying to pull 15 rows worth of information into a single column and that just doesn't work.  The `INSERT INTO SELECT` syntax is the way to go here.

Comment: actually something updating the table field. i would like to catch the last executing query which done that. so i analyse and rectify the issue. last executing queries are in the MAster Database. and i would liek to store these queries as text into my databse table.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Be aware you are going to have some serious performance issues while the trigger is in place. sys.dm_exec_sql_text is fairly slow and trying to run it every time you do an update could get interesting.